# sstop divs from overlapping

Tags: css, html, positioning

I would like to add a sidebar to a website and would like to push the existing main content to the right but certain elements float below the sidebar. Please see: http://wittmerperformance.com/site/ how do I adjust this so that the blue quote div does not extend under the side bar?

Please advise!

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the width of the element, `width: 620px` seems to achieve the desired effect. You are making things harder for you here by (ab)using inline styling and floats. I would recommend you look into [how floating content actually works](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position), as it could simplify things for you a great deal.